# Ruby mechanize login issues (encoding)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I got a simple login script that works fine up until the point it tries with letters like åäö and so on. I get no error but the login simply fails so I assume the encoding messes it up. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get("site.com/login.php")

form = page.forms.last
form.namn = 'Johan.Björk'
form.losen = 'password'
button = form.button_with(:value => "Login") 
site = agent.submit(form, button)

if site.body.include? "Wrong User/Password"
  puts 'fail'
else
  puts 'success'
end
```

Comment: What's the error? What's the encoding of your script?

Comment: The error is that the login fails for users with åäö in their names but i know the credentials are right. The encoding is utf-8 as it says in the top?

Comment: Have you tried latin1?

Comment: upvote for well-written first SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get("site.com/login.php")

form = page.forms.last
form.namn = 'Johan.Björk'
form.losen = 'password'
site = agent.submit(form, form.buttons.first)

if site.body.include? "Wrong User/Password"
  puts 'fail'
else
  puts 'success'
end
```

Also make sure you are running the latest version.